# Heroku Connect to backup Salesforce data to Postgres database

Tags: heroku, salesforce

Can we use Heroku Connect to backup millions of rows of Salesforce data to a Postgres database and keep it in sync when data changes in salesforce? Are there any known limitations of Heroku Connect such as number of rows, API limits, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

[The free demo version only allows 10,000 rows](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2015/2/24/Heroku%20Connect%20Demo%20Edition%20Now%20Available%20via%20Heroku%20Button#demo-edition-details).  If you are wanting to retrieve data more than that, pulling data to Postgres through REST API might be a cheaper option.